# How many SSL certificates (of any of the supported kinds) can be added to a single Google AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I am about to host an Nginx instance (for redirection purposes) with AppEngine, All the redirected domain names should have SSL cert over the redirection point (AppEngine) I was wondering how many SSL cert I would be able to add in a single AppEngine setting. (I might end up adding more than 100 or so domain names for redirection in there)

Comment: As per [App Engine Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl#upgrading_to_managed_ssl_certificates) , App engine issues 20 managed SSL as limit per week. Could you please explain further regarding your concerns.

Comment: @NibrassH the section you pointed me towards I believe specifically mentioned the limit for Managed certificates not other types of certs. I would like to know whether it would be possible to upload let's say about 100 private SSLs into AE in which I want to run an Nginx instance to redirect all those domains to somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine#section-5) is used to deploy apps not nginx server used as proxy for multiple domain redirecttion.

You can use [Compute Engine Virtual Machine](https://cloud.google.com/compute) for your [use-case ( Multiple SSL Certificates )](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#multiplessl). Please have a look into the following [Google Community Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/https-load-balancing-nginx) for **HTTPS load balancing using NGINX and Compute Engine**

Comment: Thank you for explaining it with patience, since apparently, my question wasn't actually the correct one to ask.